# How to change app layout RTL when language selected Arabic SwiftUI

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

Im trying to change app layout RTL when user select Arabic language . I know  .environment(.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft) is one of the solution but its not changing all app.And how can I control that for all view. Is there a way to change programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you set in rootView, like in App/Scene Delegate ?

Comment: yes it does but how can ı change that if arabic language selected ?

Answer (score 1):

```swift
class LanguageService: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = LanguageService()
    
    private init() { }
    
    @Published var selectedLanguage = Language.english
    
    enum Language: String {
        case english
        case turkish
        case arabic
        
        var isRTL: Bool {
            self == .arabic
        }
    }
}
```

And for your RootView;

```swift
RootView()
   .environment(\.layoutDirection, 
LanguageService.shared.selectedLanguage.isRTL ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight
)
   .environmentObject(LanguageService.shared)
```

You may try something similar?

Comment: I did something like this ;     @State var isRTL : Bool = false , if (arabicSelected) {   isRTL = true     .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRTL ?  .leftToRight : .rightToLeft)  but it didn't work am I missing something ?

Comment: You could set/change the language in one of your views by; 
`@EnvironmentObject var languageService: LanguageService`
`languageService.selectedLanguage = .arabic`

Comment: I did same thing but its not changing layout until I restart app.